# how to stop/ start the game without the loss of time from app delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit, appdelegate

I am trying to stop / start the game when the game goes to background due to pressing the home button, receiving a phone call etc.. I don't have the need to have a pause button in the scene so I didn't implement any pause methods but when the game gets interrupted by receiving a phone call I like to stop and start the game from the spot that was left. (I hope this explanation makes sense). currently I am using the following codes in my app delegate but it doesn't do what I want, I was wondering if there is a way to stop and start the game in app delegate so when the game goes to background all actions would stop and it would resume when the game would restart. here is my app delegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (SKView *)getGameView {
    NSArray *viewControllers = self.window.rootViewController.childViewControllers;
    for (UIViewController *vc in viewControllers) {
        if ([vc.view isKindOfClass:[SKView class]]) {
            SKView *view = (SKView *)vc.view;
            return view;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.

    SKView *view = [self getGameView];
    if (view) {
        view.paused = YES; //or NO
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.


}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    SKView *view = [self getGameView];
    if (view) {
        view.paused = NO; //or NO
    }
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Comment: "it doesn't do what i want" - what **DO** you want it to do and what is actually happening? Are you actually only having the one and only SKView that is your actual game?

Comment: the game never stops running when receiving a phone call. all actions continue and when ending the call and resuming the game, the player is dead. i just want all actions to stop when the cal is received or home button pressed, then start when the game resumes.

Comment: okay, did you make sure you actually get the actual gameView? Your current code just searches for the first view that is a `SKView` and does not make sure in any way that is actual your game.

Comment: Have you tried sending NSNotifications from your appDelegate and having the receiver in the SKScene to pause the scene?

Comment: @luk2302, is there a way to get all of the scenes to actually stop and restart from within the app delegate? how would i go about doing that?

Comment: @sangony, i haven't tried that. can you please offer a sample code? if possible.

Comment: well the easiest quick fix just for trying would be to pass the `getGameView` a boolean value indicating wether to pause or not and then iterate over everything as you currently do and then instead of returning if you found one, just set the `paused` there.

Comment: @luk2302, can't figure it out, is there any way you can help out with posting some code for that solution, if you get a chance.

Comment: I would recommend trying @imas145 solution first using notifications. In general you would be better off saving the actual gameView somewhere instead of searching for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is in the code above, which I never noticed. after an slog I found out that the view I was trying to access was till. so I changed the app delegate code to the following and it works like a charm.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.

    SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
    view.scene.paused = YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.


}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
    view.scene.paused = NO;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

basically I went back to allowing app delegate to manage every scene in my project. the code I was writing in the question above wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a notification observer directly to where you have direct access to the `SKView`, such as an view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pauseGame) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(resumeGame) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: how do you declare the selectors so the warning goes away. i get undeclared warning.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey you need to create two new functions: `-(void)pauseGame{self.view.paused=false;}` and the opposite for `resumeGame`

Comment: i get property paused not found on object of type UIView error. i tried to declare the property in view controller: @property(nonatomic, getter=isPaused) BOOL paused; didn't work. how do i get rid of the error?

Comment: What you are doing right now: declaring a property on `UIViewController` subclass and accessing it on `UIView`. What you should do: in the view controller (or wherever you create your `SKView` object), add those notification observers and methods and set the `.paused` state on your `SKView` instance.

Comment: Where do you create your `SKView` object?

Comment: in the view controller. with boilerplate code, - (void)startScene
{
    SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) {
        skView.showsFPS = NO;
        skView.showsNodeCount = NO;

        // Create and configure the scene.
        GameScene *theScene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        theScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        
        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:theScene];
    }
}

Comment: Now in that file, add this code: `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pauseGame) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(resumeGame) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81786/discussion-between-xcode-monkey-and-imas145).

Comment: @imas145, thanks for your help but the solution that you offered only works when there is only 1 skscene after the view controller and in my project there were two other before i get to my game scene. +1 for your help man.